# developing a db schema for efficient searching

Tags: algorithm, database-design, search, dictionary, geolocation

I want to implement a search  similar to as seen in http://maps.google.com/.  If I type a name of place or something i can see matching places. I know it uses AJAX.

But the major concern is fast retrieval of matching data from the database in quick time, as the user can type in almost anything.  He can type a name of  popular shop or something , or a name of a place ,or a shop followed by place name.

How can I design a database structure to make such a search?  I just need pointers.

So, any pointers about search algorithms?

Answer (score 3):

There's a whole field called spatial databases, or GIS (geospatial INformation services). Some major players are

- Oracle Spatial
- PostGIS
- ESRI
- Mapinfo

As for data structures k-d tree's are the typical spatial data structure. Lecture 3 here http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-851-advanced-data-structures-spring-2010/lecture-notes/ describes k-d trees nicely if briefly

hth